# Threading in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, multithreading

Are there threads in Objective C? If so, how are they declared and used?

If anybody knows about multithreading in Objective C, please share with me.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 18):

An easy way to just spin off a method in a new thread is to use.

`+ (void)detachNewThreadSelector:(SEL)aSelector toTarget:(id)aTarget withObject:(id)anArgument` on `NSThread`. If you aren't running garbage collected you need to set up your own autorelease pool.

Another easy way if you just don't want to block the main thread is to use.

`- (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg` on `NSObject`

Depending on what type of concurrency you are after you should also take a look at `NSOperation` that can give you free locking so you can share it between several threads among other things.

Answer (score 11):

If you're developing using Cocoa (ie for the mac or iphone), you have access to the `NSThread` class, which can be used for multithreading.  Googling for `NSThread` will find you the API.

You can declare it like using:

```
NSThread *mythread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:target selector:selector object:argument];
```

Where target and selector is the object and selector you want to start a thread with, and argument is an argument to send to the selector.

Then use [mythread start] to start it.

Answer (score 10):

Yes there are threading concepts in Objective C. and there are multiple way to achieve multi threading in objective C.

1> **NSThread**

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startTheBackgroundJob) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

This will create a new thread in the background. from your main thread.

2> **Using performSelector**

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

will perform UI task on your main thread if you call this from background thread... You can also use

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(abc:) withObject:obj];
```

Which will create a background thread.

3> **Using NSoperation**

[Follow this link](http://macresearch.org/node/4567)

4> **Using GCD**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self callWebService];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self updateUI];
        });
    });
```

Will `callWebService` in background thread and once it's completed. It will `updateUI` in main thread.[More about GCD](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-28-intro-to-grand-central-dispatch-part-i-basics-and-dispatch-queues.html)

This is almost all way of multithreading that is used in iOS. hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You could also look into [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)

To see an example of this, have a look at Drew McCormack's post on [MacResearch](http://macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxi-multi-threading-your-app-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue).

Comment: NSOperation's only supports iOS 4.0 or latter.

Answer (score 2):

Before going to far with stuff like detachNewThreadSelector: be sure to check out Apple's official documentation. For a high-level overview of options (including operation queues, dispatch queues, and such), there's the [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091). And, for a look at lower-level (and less recommended) threading, there's the [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html).

You definitely don't want to just start spinning up threads without reading what Apple has to say on the subject first. They've done a lot of work with stuff like [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) to make it easier and safer to write concurrent programs.